# Присвоение класса вложенным и предшествующим элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery, списки

Здравствуйте. Есть следующая разметка html

```js
$('.cd-main-nav li').has('ul').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-main-nav">
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>О нас</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Каталог</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Портфолио</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Контакты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>Список</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №8</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №9</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Вопрос: как присвоить новый класс (допустим .test как в примере) тегу A, который находится в LI, имеющему вложенный список UL, и предшествует этому UL.
Сейчас класс присваивается всему пункту LI.
Сколько не бился - не выходит. Помогите справиться с этой задачкой.

Comment: Правильно я вас понял - вам нужны элементы типа Пункт 6 7 8, но не Каталог и Портфолио, так?

Comment: Нет, присвоить новый класс нужно именно элементам с тегом А  "о нас" и "список"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подсветки всех вложенных элементов: [поиск элементов внутри выбранных - метод .find()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

```
$('.cd-main-nav li').has('ul').find('a').addClass('test');
```

Для подсветки родителей этих вложенных элементов: [поиск элементов лежащих перед выбранными](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8)

```
$('.cd-main-nav li ul').prev().addClass('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.cd-main-nav li').has('ul').find('a').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-main-nav">
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>О нас</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Каталог</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Портфолио</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Контакты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>Список</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №8</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №9</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Если же надо выделать только ссылки в внутреннем списке тогда -

```js
  $('.cd-main-nav li ul a').addClass('test');
```

```css
.test {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cd-main-nav">
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>О нас</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Каталог</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Портфолио</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor">Контакты</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#ankor" class="cd-subnav-trigger"><span>Список</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №6</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №7</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №8</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №9</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#ankor">Пункт №10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "О нас" и "Список" наверно не должны быть подсвечены выборкой (как мне кажется). Что-то вроде такого `$('.cd-main-nav li ul').find('a').addClass('test');`

Comment: @alexoander можно и без find тогда)

Comment: Немного наоборот: именно ссылки "О нас" и "Список" должны быть подсвечены красным.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТоршин, у вас же эти элементы сейчас уже имеют класс `cd-subnav-trigger`, можно добавить к ним еще один тогда.

Comment: cd-subnav-trigger как раз должен добавляться скриптом. test я сделал для примера.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cd-main-nav li').has('ul')
  .children('a')
    .addClass('test');
```